# Excel formula to match multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need an excel formula that will look at Location, Department Code and Job Title then return the Full Name. The problem that I am having is that locations can use the same department code and job title. There may also be multiple result which I will need to be shown in multiple cells. This will be used for an employee breakdown by location and department. I am using Excel 2016.

Example: I want to show all names that match the criteria below.

Location – Virginia

Department Code – 02023, 02023C, 02023A

Job Title – Porter, Porte/Serv, Detail, Service Porter, Detailer-Recon

[image]

This is the formula I use for positions that only have one criteria.
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$800,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$800="02021A",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$800)-ROW(Sheet1!$B$2)+1),ROWS(EMPLOYEE!$B16:$B$16))),"")}

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to to use a macro. This one will work.  Replace your sheet name with the one in your spreadsheet, place this in a module on in the VBE for the sheet.

Make sure to replace the 5 in this bit with the column where you want to print the name.

You can then filter on that column, and you have your list.

Let me know if this works.

Thanks!

```
ccccThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(intCurrentRow, 5).Value = strCurrName
```

---

```
Sub find()

Dim strLocation As String
Dim strHOmeDept As String
Dim strJobTitle As String
Dim strCurrentLoc As String
Dim strCurrHomeDept As String
Dim strCurrJobTitle As String
Dim strCurrName As String

Dim intCurrRow As Integer
Dim intEndRow As Integer



Dim i As Integer

intCurrentRow = 1
intEndRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To intEndRow

intCurrentRow = intCurrentRow + 1

strCurrentLoc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(intCurrentRow, 1).Value
strCurrHomeDept = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(intCurrentRow, 2).Value
strCurrJobTitle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(intCurrentRow, 4).Value
strCurrName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(intCurrentRow, 3).Value

If strCurrentLoc = "VIRGINIA" And _
(strCurrHomeDept = "02023" Or strCurrHomeDept = "02023C" Or strCurrHomeDept = "02023A") _
And (strCurrJobTitle = "DETAILER-RECON" Or strCurrJobTitle = "PORTER" Or strCurrJobTitle = "DETAIL" Or strCurrJobTitle = "SERVICE PORTER" _
     Or strCurrJobTitle = "PORTE/SERV") Then

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(intCurrentRow, 5).Value = strCurrName



End If

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Your code practically creates a helper column with the name matching the criteria. This could be done with a simple formula using IF, AND, OR. There is no need for macro.

Answer (score 2):

**Your issue can be solved by using Advance Filter also:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- **Copy** Headers in Row `F70:I70`.
- Enter **Criteria** in `F71, G71:G73 & I71:I74`.
- Click **Advance Filter** from **Data Tab, Sort 
  & Filter** Menu.
- Fill cell references as shown in the Advance 
  Filter dialogue below.

[image]

- Finish with **Ok**

**N.B.**

- Results may vary as Critetia been used.
- Adjust cell references as your need.